# Jquery waypoint acting buggy

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I am using waypoint to fade in elements when they appear into viewport.
Unfortunately the first image that is fading into viewport is being 1,5 of it's size for a split second and then acts normally again.

I can not see any pattern when this is happening. Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't. All the other images are fine when they appear with the plugin and are using the the same html/css.

Issue is present in Chrome.

What could be causing this?
[image]
[image]

Code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.fade-in-element').each(function(){
    var _this = this;
    var inview = new Waypoint({
        element: _this,
        handler: function (direction) {
        $(this.element).animate({'opacity': 1, 'padding-top':0 },300)},
        offset: '70%'
    });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved by removing the section wrapper div with position:relative. No idea why.

EDIT: If position:relative is still important can be solved with double wrapper

```
<div style="position:relative">
 <div style="position:inherit">
 content
 </div>
</div>
```